# How to start cordova app when internet become available

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an cordova app using ionic framework with angular.
I want app to start in background when internet connection become available so that i can fetch some notifications from server.
Is there any way to start app in background. I can keep app in background but for this it has to be in started once.

Answer (score 1):

I trink you have to create a BroadcastReceiver to be notified when an connection is established. When this happends you could start a Service which fetch some data. For your cordova app you have to write an Cordova Plugin.